# Managing APN notification for multiple users on the same phone

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, ios9

I am wondering how to manage Apple Push Notifications when many users are on the same device for the same app, because the device token is unique per device.

If I have 2 registered users on my app on the same device, how to prevent the push notification to appear if the notification is for userA but userB is currently logged into the app?

If the app is in the foreground, that could be easily managed by an userid that prevents the code to be executed if the APN is not for this user.

But how to handle this if the app is in the background?
The device will received the APN, will sound an alert, and will display the notification whatever user is currently logged into the app...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment about being able to handle the situation if the app is in the foreground, I assume the notification has some info identifying the user the notification is for.  It seems like if you store some info identifying the current user logged in, in `NSUserDefaults`, you should be able to retrieve that info in  `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and based on that decide if the notification should be handled or not.

Update adding more info:

You will also need to implement [application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) 
and turn your notification into a "silent" notification, then after you have filtered out the ones you want to display from the ones you want to suppress, you would create local notifications for those that you want to show.  You also need to add a UIBackgroundModes in your info.plist and include a "content-available", key in your payload.  See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html) for more details.

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
```

It's **critical** to implement the version with fetchCompletionHandler since the one without that is not called when the app is in background.

Here is an example from one of my apps, that receives "silent" notifications for location update requests, and also receives some "non-silent" notifications.  If the app is active I show a "toast", if the app is in the background I create a local notification from the remote notification and then trigger it.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void ) {
    log?.info("******* got a remote message = \(userInfo)  *******")
    let message: String = (userInfo["message"] ?? "stop") as! String
    log?.info("message = \(message)")
    switch message {
    case "update_locations":
      log?.info("starting location update cycle")
      locationUploader?.startUploading(handler)
    case "micropost_created":
      log?.info("got a new micropost notification")
      let notification = UILocalNotification()
      let userName = userInfo["user_name"] as? String ?? ""
      let content = userInfo["content"] as? String ?? ""
      notification.alertTitle = "Micropost from \(userName)"
      let alertBody = "\(userName) said: \(content)"
      notification.alertBody = alertBody
      notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
      application.presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
      if let topMostView = application.keyWindow {
        topMostView.makeToast(message: alertBody)
      }
      handler(.NewData)
    default:
      handler(.NoData)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes that's it, I store user information in `NSUserDefaults`. But how avoid the phone to handle the APN (screen notification, badge and sound alert) in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`?

I did it in `application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)` by putting a condition on the userid: the code that handles the APN is well not executed, but in background the phone still displays the notification, a badge and sounds an alert.

Comment: sorry I missed that you seem to be calling the version with fetchCompletionHandler already,  I think maybe the part you are missing is the content-available key in the APN payload.

Comment: No my payload does contain "content-available" set to 1: `var note = new apn.Notification(); ... note.contentAvailable = 1;`

Comment: Ok I got it by reading Apple doc again: For a silent notification, take care to ensure there is no alert, sound, or badge payload in the aps dictionary. If you don’t follow this guidance, the incorrectly-configured notification might be throttled and not delivered to the app in the background, and instead of being silent is displayed to the user.
I forgot to remove alert, sound and badge from my APN!

Answer (score 1):

For resolving the above issue i have two options
 1. On logout remove the token from server DB for logged in user and every time when new user gets login into app request for new token and send onto server. 
 2. On logout app can unregister itself from notification center and on login app has to register it self for notification and update token on server.

Here is the code for register and unregister notification.
On logout: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];

On login:

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];